# Moving the labels on a plot away from the line

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I have a dataframe like this;

```
TEST1 <- data.frame(
    Number = c(46.68, 46.45, 48.35, 44.63, 45.65, 46.46, 45.14, 45.69, 47.10),
    House.Height= c("LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "MODERATE", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH"))
```

I have created a boxplot using this code:

```
    ggboxplot(TEST1, x = "House.Height", y = "Number", fill = "House.Height", palette = c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), order = c("LOW", "MODERATE", "HIGH"), sort.by.groups = TRUE,
          label = TRUE, label.pos = "out", lab.vjust = -2
) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("low", "moderate", "high")) +
    xlab("House Height")+ ylab("Number") + 
    labs(fill = "House"
    ) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(44,50)) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(44, 50))
```

However, I can see from the outcome that one of the labels (46.45) in the "LOW" bar is on the line, and you can barley see the dots in the 44.63 and 45.14.
[image: Bar Plot Outcome]

Is there a way to move them downwards so that they can be more visible. I thought vjust would have it, but obviously, it did not. I have also tried using various scales for the yaxis without any success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `repel=TRUE` option?

[image]

Or you could use `ggplot` with `geom_label_repel` to get a nicer outcome:

```
ggplot(TEST1 , aes(x=House.Height, y=Number, fill=House.Height)) + geom_boxplot() + theme_bw() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")) + 
  theme_bw()  +
  theme(legend.position = "top") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("LOW", "MODERATE", "HIGH")) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(aes(label=Number), force=1.5, fill=hsv(0,0,1,alpha=0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to achieve this using geom_boxplot within ggplot because then you can simply use geom_text which is very straightforward to adjust using nudge_x and nudge_y. I also re-arranged the factor levels prior to plotting and put your palette in scale_fill_manual.

```
TEST1$House.Height <- factor(TEST1$House.Height, levels = c('LOW', 'MODERATE', 'HIGH'))

ggplot(TEST1, aes(x = House.Height, y = Number))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = House.Height)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("low", "moderate", "high")) +
  xlab("House Height")+ ylab("Number") + 
  labs(fill = "House") + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(44,50)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(44, 50)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Number, x = House.Height, y = Number), nudge_x = 0.5, size = 3) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

[image]